# Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes in Cassandra Datastax while insert data

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-enterprise

When I try to Insert data in Cassandra using the below query I am getting the below mentioned error

```
cqlsh:assign> insert into tblFiles1(rec_no,clientid,contenttype,datafiles,filename) values(1,2,'gd','dgfsdg','aww');
```

> WriteTimeout: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for
>   replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only
>   0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1,
>   'consistency': 'ONE'}

**My Version of `Cassandra` and `DSE`:**
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.5.469 | DSE 4.7.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protoco                                                                                                                     l v3]

Comment: Can you check/post cassandra.log from your nodes?

Comment: The results of a [trace](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html) on the query may also be useful.

Comment: ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}

While giving a select query i get this error. Please give a solution for this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Increase the `write_request_timeout_in_ms` Timeout in the Cassandra Config file (**cassandra.yaml**) as

```
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
```

and restart your Server