# Sporadic Cassandra WriteErrors when using Lightweight Transactions

Tags: cassandra

I have a service that connects to our Cassandra cluster and executes tens of thousands of queries per day using [Lightweight (ACID) Transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_tunable_consistency_c.html) to implement the Consensus system desribed [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_tunable_consistency_c.html). For the most part it works fine, but sporadically, the writes will fail with the error saying "Operation timed out - received only 1 responses" (or less commonly, only  0 responses). We're using the Datastax Python driver. When the error occurs, the full error line (at the end of the stack trace) reads:

```
WriteTimeout: Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 1 responses." info={'received_responses': 1, 'required_responses': 2, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_SERIAL'}
```

Is this something that seems expected to occur from time to time in a production Cassandra setup? Or does it seem like something where we could have a configuration problem with our Cassandra cluster or network?

Some information about our Cassandra cluster: It is an 8-node setup spread across 2 Amazon EC2 regions (4 nodes per region). All of the nodes are running version 3.3.0 of the Datastax Cassandra distribution.

Comment: Same problem here, just to add: all SO answers related to this problem are about increasing timeouts. In my case WriteTimeout is received 10-100ms seconds after the request is started, and my all timeouts are >10s in cassandra yaml config.

I think this could also be Datastax Python cassandra client problem..

Comment: FYI, none of those are helpful:
[answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575125/coordinator-node-timed-out-waiting-for-replica-nodes-in-cassandra-datastax-while), 
[answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194860/cassandra-coordinator-node-timed-out-waiting-for-replica-nodes-responses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

From https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9328

> There is cases where under contention the coordinator loses track of
>   whether the value it submitted to Paxos might be applied or not (see
>   CASSANDRA-6013). At which point we can't do anything else that
>   answering "sorry I don't know". And since a WriteTimeoutException
>   already means "I don't know", we throw it in that case too, even
>   though it's not a proper timeout per-se